# Cutting Element in Unix Based on Column Value

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Without a shell script, in a single line. What command can help you cut from a row based on the column value

For example:

In

```
118 Balboni,Steve 23
11 Baker,Doug 0
120 Armas,Tony 13
133 Allanson,Andy 5
158 Baines,Harold 13
33 Bando,Chris 1
44 Adduci,James 1
50 Aguayo,Luis 3
5 Allen,Rod 0
94 Anderson,Brady 1
```

IF there 3rd row is not zero, how do I remove the row entirely in one statement? Is this possible in unix?

Comment: 3rd row?  Or do you mean 3rd column?  How many ways do you want to do it?  `awk`, `sed`, `perl`, `python` could all do it with ease (some slightly more easily than others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the question is really asking about 'if the third column is non-zero, do not print it' or (equivalently) 'only print the row if the third column is 0':

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$3 == 0' data
```

(If the third column is zero, print the input; otherwise, ignore it.  You could add `{ print }` after the `0` to make the action explicit.)

Using `perl`:

```
perl -nae 'print if $F[2] == 0' data
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/ 0$/p' data
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grep:

```
grep '[^0-9]0$' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the inplace replacement.

```
perl -i -F -pane 'undef $_ if($F[2]!=0)' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
118 Balboni,Steve 23
11 Baker,Doug 0
120 Armas,Tony 13
133 Allanson,Andy 5
158 Baines,Harold 13
33 Bando,Chris 1
44 Adduci,James 1
50 Aguayo,Luis 3
5 Allen,Rod 0
94 Anderson,Brady 1
>
>
> perl -i -F -pane 'undef $_ if($F[2]!=0)' temp
> cat temp
11 Baker,Doug 0
5 Allen,Rod 0
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to print lines that have no third column as well as those in which the 3rd column is explicitly `0` (ie, if you consider a blank field to be zero), try:

```
awk '!$3'
```

If you do not want to print lines with only 2 columns, try:

```
awk 'NF>2 && !$3'
```